# std::enable_if for std::is_integral and its negation both show as ambiguous candidate overloads

Tags: c++, c++17

I have some API that serializes values. I have created a wrapper that helps by having a simple one method that should accept all supported types.

Most types require explicit implementation, but all integer types are accepted by single method on that API. I wrote this code:

```
// Used to allow for human readable error on missing overload
template<typename T>
struct fail_if_invoked : std::false_type
{ };

// This overload should get selected if value is not integer type and explicit overload does not exist
template<typename TVal, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<TVal>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void accept_value(TVal && vadd)
{
    static_assert(fail_if_invoked<TVal>::value, "Missing implementation for this type");
}

// This overload should handle all integer types
template<typename TInteger, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<TInteger>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void accept_value(TInteger num)
{
    ...
}

void accept_value(const char*) 
{
    ...
}
```

However, when `unsigned int` is the argument to `accept_value`, I get an error about ambiguous call, for these overloads:

```
my_helper.h:37:10: note: candidate function [with TVal = unsigned short &, $1 = nullptr]
    void accept_value(TVal && vadd)
         ^
my_helper.h:44:10: note: candidate function [with TInteger = unsigned short, $1 = nullptr]
    void accept_value(TInteger num)
         ^
my_helper.h:59:10: note: candidate function
    void accept_value(double num)
         ^
my_helper.h:79:10: note: candidate function
    void accept_value(bool num)
```

I sort of understand the `bool` and `double`, although it wasn't an issue when I had explicit overloads for everything. But why is the `void add_value(TVal && vadd)` still in the list when `!std::is_integral<TVal>` should disable it?

And is it even possible to have generic implementation for all integral types while also having `bool` and `double` overloads?

Comment: fwiw the `_t` and `_v` helper aliases make the code much more readable

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: fwiw, repro: https://godbolt.org/z/nEbW9c8Tr

Comment: _"And is it even possible to have generic implementation for all integral types while also having bool and double overloads?"_ — Yes, it's possible: https://godbolt.org/z/xz4qda8c7.

Comment: @DanielLangr You should post that as an alternative answer. I am stuck with `C++17`, but this is good to know! Way cleaner.

Comment: Which C++ version are you on? With c++17 it can be simplified a bit, with C++20 you can switch to concepts for a cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the template parameter in `std::decay_t` to get the raw type without any reference or const, because `std::integral<int&>` will evaluate to false.

**Update - additional explanation**

The signature `accept_value(TVal && vadd)` accepts the parameter using an rvalue-reference (often called a universal reference). If you pass a variable of type `int`, `TVal` will deduce to `int&`. If you pass a literal integer like `1`, `TVal` will deduce to `int`. Without the `std::decay_t`, this will cause different results when `std::is_integral` is evaluated. Overload resolution will behave accordingly.

**End Update**

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Used to allow for human readable error on missing overload
template<typename T>
struct fail_if_invoked : std::false_type
{ };

// This overload should get selected if value is not integer type and explicit overload does not ex\
ist
template<typename TVal,
         typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<std::decay_t<TVal>>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void accept_value(TVal && vadd)
{
    static_assert(fail_if_invoked<TVal>::value, "Missing implementation for this type");
}

// This overload should handle all integer types
template<typename TInteger,
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<std::decay_t<TInteger>>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void accept_value(TInteger num)
{
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int a{};
    accept_value(a);
    accept_value(1);
    accept_value("char");
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
/work/so/scratch/src/p1.cpp:16:5: error: static assertion
      failed due to requirement 'fail_if_invoked<const char (&)[5]>::value': Missing
      implementation for this type
    static_assert(fail_if_invoked<TVal>::value, "Missing implementation for this type");
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/work/so/scratch/src/p1.cpp:30:5: note: in instantiation of
      function template specialization 'accept_value<const char (&)[5], nullptr>' requested here
    accept_value("char");
    ^
1 error generated.
```

**Update**

As an aside, this gets much easier with `c++20`

```cpp
template<class T> requires (not std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>)
void accept_value(T&& vadd)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>, "Missing implementation for this type");
}

template<class T> requires (std::is_integral_v<std::decay_t<T>>)
void accept_value(T&& num)
{
}
```

Comment: fwiw, its the combination of `TVal && vadd` and `TInteger num` that gets the two types deduced differently. For me it was a little surprise that both overloads pass, but thats because `TInteger num` is a value

Comment: Do you have any clue why in my original code, `bool` and `double` overloads were mentioned as candidates, but when I used your solution that's no longer a problem and the integer overload gets selected?

Comment: @TomášZato how do you call it? When I try I only get the two overloads mentioned https://godbolt.org/z/1YeT8aTvq

Comment: I added some additional explanation in the answer. The `rvalue-reference` will deduce to slightly different types (`int` versus `int&`) depending on how you call the function. Without the `std::decay_t`, `std::is_integral` will evaluate differently and the overload resolution will behave accordingly.